# How to load-string to current namespace (not core)?

Tags: namespaces, clojure

I can load arbitrary Clojure source using:

`(load-string source)`

However, if namespace wasn't provided, it loads code to `clojure.core` namespace.

For example, following code:

`(load-string "(defn add [a b] (+ a b))")`

defines a function:

`#'clojure.core/add`

Now, is there a way to load that code to some other namespace, preferably the same one in which `load-string` function is called?

(Other than prepending a namespace declaration to `source` string before evaluation. I know that it would solve the problem - I'd like to know is there a preferred way)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

when `def` needs to decide what namspace a new function should go in it looks at the the current value of the `ns` var and adds the new function to that namespace. because `ns` is a var you can dynamically bind it before you call load-string

```
user> (binding [*ns* (find-ns 'foo)] (load-string "(defn f [] 4)"))
#'foo/f
user> (foo/f)
4
```